# Как работает под капотом поиск запчастей по VIN

Tags: веб-программирование, интернет-магазин, поисковые-системы

Столкнулся с необходимостью создания интернет магазина, где должна быть функция поиска запчастей по VIN. Вопрос: Откуда подобные сайты берут информацию? Неужели у каждого есть своя база? Это же просто тонны информации о моделях автомобилей. Ладно ещё модели, которых и так тысячи, но там поколения, рестайлинги, разные страны выпуска, разные года, движки, коробки и это всё может быть у одной модели. Если я скажу заказчику, что ему это всё надо заполнять, то у него кукуха поедет. Возможно есть какая-то общая открытая база с API, откуда можно брать информацию? Мб это как-то по-другому должно работать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Была такая база из программы TECDOC.
Раньше она весила 20+Гб.
Но, современная версия вроде как без картинок и потому умещается на DVD.

Официально можно купить программу здесь https://www.tecalliance.net/en/products-and-solutions/data/

Неофициально - ищите на трекерах.

Покупаете вы программу, а не базу. Саму базу надо еще выкуривать от туда. Когда я выкуривал от туда данные, это был простой `.mdb`-файл (база данных Microsoft Access). Файл был огромный, картинки хранились прямо в базе.

Но сейчас, скорее всего, что-нибудь изменилось.

**UPDATE**

У TecAlliance есть сайт на русском https://tecdoc.moscow/

Простым поиском можно наткнуться на этих ребят: https://www.tecdoc.ru/ (некий ТехДоктор)

Этот ТехДоктор к TECDOC по сути отношения никакого не имеют, но что-то продают отсылая на сайт https://autodatabases.ru/

Цены аховые, но есть к каждой базе доступ по API: https://partsapi.ru/

На API цены вроде не кусаются, и есть [документация каждого метода](https://partsapi.ru/documentation.html).

Comment: autodatabases.ru не советую, был печальный опыт работы. Покупали у них базу TecDoc, документация такая, что можно сказать ее нет, самостоятельно разобраться не получится, много дублей, не актуальных связей и просто отсутствующих данных, в общем использовать в работе не реально

Answer (score 4):

Для этого существует TecDoc, большие базы с большим количеством запчастей, вот только я не помню уже там есть оригинальные запчасти или нет.

Покупаете или находите в открытом доступе, но мне кажется лучше купить актуальную и с ней работаете.